# Binary as list of 1s and 0s to int

Tags: python

I would like to convert a list of integer 1s and 0s which represent a binary number to an int.

something along the lines of:

```
>>> [1,1,0,1].toint()
```

would give an output of `13`

Comment: What do you want `[1, 1, 0, 1]` to become?  (Your example is symmetric, so it's not clear what significance order you prefer.)

Comment: @DSM excellent point, fixed

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Strings are unnecessary here:

```
>>> l = [1,1,0,1]
>>> 
>>> sum(j<<i for i,j in enumerate(reversed(l)))
13
```

---

**Relevant documentation:**

- [`sum()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)
- [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)
- [`reversed()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed)

Comment: Glad to find a non-string method. Bonus: this is faster.

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
>>> int(''.join(map(str, my_list)), 2)
5
```

Answer (score 3):

Look at this:

```
>>> x = [1,1,0,1]
>>> int("".join(map(str, x)), 2)
13
>>>
```