# Converting a list of numbers into a binary number base 10

Tags: python, list, binary

How do you convert a list of 0 and 1's into a binary number with base 10? 
For example: `([0,0,1,0,0,1])` will give me 9

Comment: Dup of lots of questions, including [this recent one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19883285/binary-as-list-of-1s-and-0s-to-int), which has a nice accepted answer.

Answer (score 8):

try this:

```
int("".join(str(x) for x in a),2)
```

Convert the list into a string. And then make the binary to decimal conversion

Answer (score 4):

Well this is quite simple:

```
>>> a = [0,0,1,0,0,1]
>>> s = "".join(map(str, a))
>>> s
'001001'
>>> int(s, base=2)
9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `int` function with the second parameter which indicates the base. As, the list is full of numbers, that has to be converted to a string (`int` accepts only string), so we do `map(str, data)`

```
print "".join(map(str, data))
```

**Output**

```
001001
```

So, it boils down to this

```
data = [0,0,1,0,0,1]
print int("".join(map(str, data)), 2)
```

**Output**

```
9
```